# Use Unity animation in native iOS application

Tags: ios, animation, unity-game-engine, after-effects

I want to create a small animation in Unity and integrate this animation with **Native iOS Application**.

Looked into many possible solutions, but they were not useful. I don't want the animation in a video format.

Just for the sake of more info that may help, here is some of my research that I have tried out. I created the animation using After Effects, exported it as a Unity animation, and then reimported it into Unity; but when I exported it as an iOS application, it was not able to separate out 
this animation sequence for my native application. There was a way in After Effects where I could export the animation as video file but that's not what I want.

Comment: I have added my research.

Comment: So you do have attempted a solution, in that case you should ask why this solution failed to work and include your code and other steps you took.

Comment: A very useful question. I also had the same type of requirement for my application. And was able to achieve this by referring to these simple steps provided in following URL : http://www.the-nerd.be/2014/08/06/add-unity3d-in-a-native-ios-application/

Answer (score 0):

You can create bindings in either direction, such as Objective-C bindings for Unity, or vice versa. You can also use plug-ins, but they're a premium feature, more details here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html

If you can convert your animation objects to obj files, you can import them that way also. If that doesn't work, you can use Blender3D to create models, and import them obj files.